# Create a sequence not related to any primary key in Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I need to create a sequence whose value is going to be read by call to `.NEXTVAL` in PL/SQL code and saved in more then one record of a specific table column, so my design doesn't require to define a PK on the aforementioned column.

I cannot find out how to edit the sequence tab in Oracle Data Modeler (I'm on version 4.1.1) when the PK checkbox is not selected (all the sequence related fields are disabled).

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the relational model, choose your DB and within that you will find sequence as an item to create. You can also create other types of object here.